# IBM MobileFirst Detect Application Version Update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

During version update, user will receive an update notification once he active the app, an update alert box will pop up, and he/she is able to choose "Update" or "Cancel" the update request.

How do I detect the action(Update/Cancel) user choose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the feature as provided by default in the product, you cannot.

In order to do such "detection", you will need to implement Custom Direct Update, but it doesn't sound like a full customization is needed in your case, so you can take a look at the following example under "customizing the UI": https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/#userExprience

In the example code, there is additional code that either starts or cancels the update process, so it is this spot that you could add additional code to "know" that it was either started or canceled.

```
wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData,
directUpdateContext) {
    // custom WL.SimpleDialog for Direct Update
    var customDialogTitle = 'Custom Title Text';
    var customDialogMessage = 'Custom Message Text';
    var customButtonText1 = 'Update Application';
    var customButtonText2 = 'Not Now';

    WL.SimpleDialog.show(customDialogTitle, customDialogMessage,
        [{
            text : customButtonText1,
            handler : function() {
                directUpdateContext.start();
                // Additional code here.
            }
        },
        {
            text : customButtonText2,
            handler : function() {
                wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                // Additional code here.
            }
        }]
    );
};
```